# rails - one action, many templates - what is the rails way to handle this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Lets use the PeopleController#show action as an example.   What if I need to display a person several different ways depending on the application.  I have a few options based on the request format (js, html) but I really need more.

I could make different controller actions but I prefer to keep my controllers basic unless I have no sensible alternative.  Another idea would be to have a case statement and a template parameter, but that seems to be bothersome as well (particularly if certain views are for certain user types).

My question is: what is the rails way to do this?

people_controller.rb

```
def show
  set_partial
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

protected
def set_partial
  @template = case params[:template]
                when 'small' then 'small_view'
                when 'quick' then 'quick_view'
                else
                  'full_view'
              end
end
```

people/show.js.erb

```
$('body').append("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: @partial) %>")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi friend this might help you.

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
   if (condition)
    format.js { render :template => "small_view" }
    #renders small_view.js.erb
    format.html { render :template => "small_view" }
    #renders small_view.html.erb
   elsif (condition)
    format.js { render :template => "quick" }
    format.html { render :template => "quick" }
   elsif (condition)
    format.js { render :template => "full_view" }
    format.html { render :template => "full_view" }
   else
    format.html
    format.js
   end
  end
end
```